# How do I change TabView from a button in a separate file?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to create a button that changes the TabView when tapped. Everything I have tried so far has not worked. I think need to use the @Binding property wrapper for currentTab but can't seem to get it to work.

Here is the file with the TabView:

```
struct MainPage: View {

    @StateObject var appModel: AppViewModel = .init()
    @Namespace var animation
    
    // Hiding Tab Bar...
    
    init () {
        UITabBar.appearance().isHidden = true
    }

    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 0){
            
            // Tab View...
            TabView(selection: $appModel.currentTab) {
                
                
                View1()
                    .tag(Tab.View1)
                    .setUpTab()
                
                View2()
                    .tag(Tab.View2)
                    .setUpTab()
                
                View3()
                    .tag(Tab.View3)
                    .setUpTab()
            
                
                View4()
                    .tag(Tab.View4)
                    .setUpTab()
                
                View5()
                    .tag(Tab.View5)
                    .setUpTab()
            }
            .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
                CustomTabBar(currentTab: $appModel.currentTab, animation: animation)
                    .offset(y: appModel.showDetailViewTab ? 150 : 0)
            }
       }
    }
```

Here is the AppViewModel file:

```
class AppViewModel: ObservableObject {
   
    @Published var currentTab: Tab = .Market
     
}
```

Here is the button I want to change the tab view:

```
struct View1Button: View {  
    var body: some View {

        
        Button(action: {

            print("Take to View1 Button Tapped...")

        }) {
            HStack {
                Image("View1Icon")
                VStack {
                    Text("Go to View1")
                }
            }
            }
        }  
    }  
}
```

How do I change the tab view when this button is tapped?

Comment: Import `AppViewModel` to your `View1Button` struct as you did in `MainPage` and change it's value.

Comment: When I did that it didn't work, I just tried it again and it still doesn't. In the button I wrote appModel.currentTab = .View1. I added some prints to find out what's happening. The app launches on view 1, then I tap view 3 in the tab bar. This is where the button is. When the button is tapped it thinks it's already in View1. When the button is tapped it changes currentTab value but doesn't take me anywhere even when I change the destination.

Answer (score 1):

I think this code does what you are trying to achieve.

Basically, you have to share the state property among the views. This way, the tab can be changed programmatically.

```
enum Tab {
    case View1
    case View2
    case View3
    case View4
    case View5
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var appModel = AppViewModel()
    
    init () {
        UITabBar.appearance().isHidden = true
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            TabView(selection: $appModel.currentTab) {
                CustomView(tab: $appModel.currentTab, viewNumber: 1)
                    .tag(Tab.View1)
                
                CustomView(tab: $appModel.currentTab, viewNumber: 2)
                    .tag(Tab.View2)
                
                CustomView(tab: $appModel.currentTab, viewNumber: 3)
                    .tag(Tab.View3)
                
                CustomView(tab: $appModel.currentTab, viewNumber: 4)
                    .tag(Tab.View4)
                
                CustomView(tab: $appModel.currentTab, viewNumber: 5)
                    .tag(Tab.View5)
            }
            .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
                CustomTabBar(currentTab: $appModel.currentTab)
            }
        }
    }
}

class AppViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var currentTab: Tab = .View1
}

struct CustomView: View {
    @Binding var tab: Tab
    let viewNumber: Int
    
    private let views: [Tab] = [.View1, .View2, .View3, .View4, .View5]
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("I'm view number \(viewNumber)") {
            tab = views.randomElement()!
        }
    }
}

struct CustomTabBar: View {
    @Binding var currentTab: Tab
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 25) {
            TabButton(currentTab: $currentTab, name: "1.circle.fill", tab: .View1)
            
            TabButton(currentTab: $currentTab, name: "2.circle.fill", tab: .View2)
            
            TabButton(currentTab: $currentTab, name: "3.circle.fill", tab: .View3)
            
            TabButton(currentTab: $currentTab, name: "4.circle.fill", tab: .View4)
            
            TabButton(currentTab: $currentTab, name: "5.circle.fill", tab: .View5)
        }
    }
}

struct TabButton: View {
    @Binding var currentTab: Tab
    let name: String
    let tab: Tab
    
    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: name)
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
            .foregroundColor(currentTab == tab ? .red : .blue)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to share the state property among the views using the .tag(Tab.View1) part? Making lots of changes to the structure of the tab bar in this way causes lots of issues. If possible I want to keep the tab bar the largely the same but want one button to change the tab. Can't this be done by making a change to currentTab or using .tag(Tab.View1)?

Comment: I’m afraid this is not possible. The only way to share an editable property among different views is through an object. You can share it as a StateObject or as a EnvironmentObject but not through the tag view modifier.

Comment: I see, I want to take the user to their profile tab when they click the profile icon in the top right. Is your answer the way to go about doing this? When I try to apply this the initialiser throws up an error. If your answer is a good way to go, ill post any errors I run into!